# Linux as a router

Tags: routing, vpn

I'm wondering whether this would be possible with linux and how ...
I've got a normal DSL connection and 3 VPNs - I'd like a Linux computer to connect to all connections (maybe through a DSL Router or not - shouldn't matter) and then offer those connections to the internal network/my desktop PC and Laptop and Smartphone.

In case I access websites/hosts in a certain area (country) then it should use the DSL connection.
In case I access websites/hosts in other parts of the world, it should use VPN.
Here, Linux should load the required data via the fastest connection currently available (the 3 VPNs aren't always fast/stable so I'd like to switch dynamically).

And chance of getting this done?

Comment: Linux is what runs most routers, so probably you're already doing this.

Comment: I recommend searching for "linux box as a router" and following the initial setup from one of the many guides available. Then ask a specific question if you are having any issues with that and can't find an answer on your own.

Comment: Hmm .. I searched a bit more and found something interesting on the multiple connections:
https://lukecyca.com/2004/howto-multirouting-with-linux.html
I'll try this first and then see whether I can get more detailed questions along the way.